# How to get the value of a data-amount JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to get the value of a data-amount JMeter
I tried to get the value using a xpath extractor. But I always got an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Code screenshot]

```
//*[@class = 'panel-body']//*[@class='fade-in'][1]/@data-amount
```

[image: XPath Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of problems with your XPath expression, for instance:

```
//*[@class = 'panel-body']//*[@class='fade-in'][1]/@data-amount
                           ^ - extra slash      ^ - not required
```

I also don't like `*` wildcard, however it might be a weird form of your test scenario so let it be.

Being converted to "normal" XPath expression it should look something like:

```
//*[@class='panel-body']/*/@data-amount
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter XPath Extractor]

It may be simplified to something like:

```
//div[@data-action='bid_online']/@data-amount
```

References:

- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)